# Why flock() works differently when the File object is new?

Tags: ruby, io

Here is the code and it works:

```
f = File.new('test', File::CREAT | File::RDWR)
f.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
f.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
puts 'Works!'
```

However, this one doesn't work:

```
File.new('test', File::CREAT | File::RDWR).flock(File::LOCK_EX)
File.new('test', File::CREAT | File::RDWR).flock(File::LOCK_EX)
puts 'Works!'
```

Can you explain why is that? My actual question is how to make the second snippet work?

Comment: How do you understand, that second example doesn't work?

Comment: @Milovidov well, I ran it and it didn't print `Works!` :)

Comment: Because it shouldn't print 'Works!' :)

Comment: First snippet has _same_ file descriptor for two lock attempts, while second snippet - _different_ ones. Than read Tulentsev's second quote again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to make the second snippet work?

Unlock the file with `LOCK_UN` before attempting relocking with `LOCK_EX`. Or don't use `LOCK_EX`.

As to why this happens, see the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) on `flock(2)`.

> If a process uses `open(2)` (or similar) to obtain more than one file
>          descriptor for the same file, these file descriptors are treated
>          independently by `flock()`.  An attempt to lock the file using one of
>          these file descriptors may be denied by a lock that the calling
>          process has already placed via another file descriptor.

Comment: But I want to call `flock()` twice. And I want it to work on the second call, just like it worked with the first. And I need to use a new `File` object.

Comment: @yegor256: yes, yes, just unlock it, and then you can lock it again.